# Unable to load CSS files into Django 1.10

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I am developing a dynamic website which include CSS in it.
I am using template inheritance.When I try to include CSS files I am getting a "404 Page not Found" error for CSS file. Please help me.

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Here's my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^courses/', include('courses.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Here's my settings.py file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5%#*z=7o5iap!lnr7(%*(2rsl#*b-ufjy!ia$8z08d(6d8!j-#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'courses',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Here's my layout.html file:

```
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
        {% block title %}{% endblock title %}
    </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}print something for fun...{% endblock content %}
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my home.html file:

```
    {% extends 'layout.html' %}
    {% block title %}Hello World {% endblock title%}

    {% block eontent %}
    <h1>
      welcome!!!
    </h1>
   {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: in your base html try to change this `{% load static from staticfiles %}` into `{% load static %}`

Comment: It's not working @Shift N' Tab

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.10

here is the documentation of [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)

change your

```
STATIC_FILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

to

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    'static',
]
```

And in your base html change the `{% load static from staticfiles %}` to `{% load static %}`

> **STATIC_FILES_DIRS**  is no django settings config name use **STATICFILES_DIRS** instead.

Comment: I have another small query, I renamed the static directory to "assets" and then I opened the website, I found the link to the CSS file to be  <link rel='stylesheet' href="/static/css/layout.css">...What is happening here? Why is it still showing ''static''? @Shift N' Tab

Comment: i do not recommend that you rename the static folder since django always find the static folder name based on your settings.py if you want to change the name then you must change your static definition in your settings.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. It worked even when static definition is left unchanged (i.e. STATIC_URL='/static/'). I wonder why.@Shift N' Tab

Answer (score 0):

If your static folder is inside you base project app . 
Something like.

```
django_project (your manage.py is here) -> django_project -> static
```

then your static file config should be like.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_project/static'),
)
```

You shouldn't need any changes in your urls for this.

**Update**: The above doesn't seem to be true. 
Your template syntax for block tag is incorrect.

Can you please fix that and check . You don't `endblock and blockname`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}print something for fun...{% endblock %}
  </body>

</html>
```

Update 2:

Also template context process needs to be like this.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: The above template tag fix is true for your home.html as well.